# Freezing lake at a depth

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, phase-transition, heat-conduction, steady-state

[image: I have a attached a image file for clearer depiction]

The above image depicts the freezing of lake at depth y, on which I have this doubt...

I understand that at **t**=0, lake starts to freeze from top layer due to anomalous density variations of water. After time **t**, the lake will be froze upto depth **y**. The next **dy** depth will be at 0°C during freezing process and freezing is possible only if water layer **dy** releases corresponding heat energy **dQ**.

**But wouldn't that heat dQ disturb the steady state of ice above it?**

*I mean wouldn't the ice above dy absorb the heat and show temperature variations or perhaps even melt back to water?*

I wonder how will the freezing be affected if the adjacent ice melts to water...

Comment: You're right that the heat must flow "up": the Second Law requires that in the transfer of heat between two bodies, heat flows from the high temperature object to the low temperature object.  But this system is not in equilibrium, so there is no requirement that the ice at the bottom of the frozen section is at the same temperature as the water just below it (at $0^{\rm o}$C).  Heat released from the freezing water could be absorbed by the ice above to raise its temperature via $Q = c_{\rm ice} \, m \, \Delta T$, at some $T_{\rm ice} < 0^{\rm o}$, without melting it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the heat balance of the layer of height $y$: It receives heat d$Q$ from the layer below, but can also give off heat to the air above it. If the heat given off to the air is lower than the amount of heat received from below, then you're right: the layer above in the long run will melt. But if it is giving off enough heat, it doesn't have to melt.